# Read data from OMRON Blood Pressure Monitor with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am doing a project to read blood pressure from the OMRON 708-BT device using bluetooth. I have managed to connect and read data.

When I  press upload button, I got three data reports from the device

1.

e2000032800000000001002a507900268000000080008000000000000000008000000008002209225835744e400000010100000000000000000

2.
e70000da00d80024020300d20000000a00cc0928002000104f4d524f4e204845414c544843415245000c48454d2d373038312d4954000984000a0008002209225835744e0a5a000800010004100700010a4400024000092d00360002003200010001001653455249414c5f4e554d4245523a200000000000004100050001001046575f5245564953494f4e3a203130310914000400005dc00a4b0016000200120201000801000001000200070202000200000a450010c0101f00ffffffff00640000000000000a550008000100040a620006098700082014112511100800

3.
e4000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

My question, how to parse these data to meaning full values and which correct data?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

thanks

Comment: You might want to remove "bpm" tag as this is used for "Business Process Management" not "Beats Per Minute".

Comment: did you find solution?